# mount cifs: how to retrieve the status of the command execution from the terminal?

Tags: mount, stdout, cifs, command-substitution

The following `mount cifs` code works fine:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.77/something /mnt/192.168.1.77/something \
           -o username=alpha,rw,uid=alpha,gid=tango,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
```

through a shell script when it is executed in the terminal appears a new line with:

```
� Password for alpha@//192.168.1.77/something:
```

If the password is correct the terminal does not write/put/show nothing and the directory is mounted as expected. But If the password is incorrect, it shows

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

I want create a loop iterating always while: if any error message appears in the terminal to execute again the command and therefore ask for the password. Of course if the password is correct and the `mount cifs` returns something that indicates all is ok, the loop must be stop.

How accomplish this? I tried *Command Substitution*:

```
result=$(sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.77/something /mnt/192.168.1.77/something \
           -o username=alpha,rw,uid=alpha,gid=tango,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,nounix,sec=ntlmssp)
echo "result: '${result}'"
```

and happens the following:

```
# Valid password scenario
� Password for alpha@//192.168.1.77/something:
result: ''

# Invalid password scenario
� Password for alpha@//192.168.1.77/something:
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
result: ''
```

How you can see even with *Command Substitution* is not possible how it would be expected. Always is empty the *result* variable.

Not sure if exists a parameter for `mount cifs` that enable returns something to then let the *result* variable show something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just test for $? that should contain the exit code from mount which in this case should be 13 or 0 if it succeeded.

If you want an error message, run `errno $?`, although you may have to install `errno` from some package.

Comment: interesting, even when the error is `mount error(13): Permission denied` - 13 is shown - `$?` shows `32`

Comment: @Manuel-Jordan That will be because `mount` sets up a pipe to and calls `mount.cifs`, which when fails, tears down the pipe and that is the error that `mount` returns. If you were to call `mount.cifs` directly, you should get the correct error number returned.